# Android Studio not getting notification payload while app is not running

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I want to log notification payload while app is not running. I put a debug log in `onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {}` when app is in foreground getting payload in log but when app is not running and getting a notification then log not show notification payload in android studio.